# Communicate from Android VM app to a Vagrant [web service] app

Tags: android, vagrant

So basically I have a Android application in a VM (I run&debug it via Android Studio). 
It communicates with a php RESTful webservice app: https://mywebservice.mydomain.com .
I want it to actually communicate with my local web service app (not the real live server on mywebservice.mydomain.com).
When I had my web service app running directly on a WAMP-ish setup, this was easy... 
I could just create a hosts file with:

```
10.0.2.2 mywebservice.mydomain.com
```

and do a 'adb push hosts /etc/system/hosts' to the VM while its running.
The Android VM considers 10.0.2.2 to be the host box so mywebservice.mydomain.com would actually be my personal WAMP VirtualHost and not the real live server. 
Note on my own box's hosts file, I have this so I can access this VirtualHost directly in  my Window's browser (if I wanted to easily go in and change some admin settings in the web service for example):

```
127.0.0.1 mywebservice.mydomain.com
```

(and all this makes it easy so I can debug the full app, from localhost Android App changes to my localhost php web-service changes, or just check out the php web service app directly on Windows [it has a login Admin UI]).

Now I'd like the web-service php app to be running not in WAMP but in a Vagrant linux box (which I already got running and can access from my Windows browser, pretend for now via the default puphpet url https://awesome.dev. Now sure I can change that to be mywebservice.mydomain.com instead and accessible via Windows), but I couldn't figure out how to get my Android VM app to 'point' there still (via hosts file or some alternate method like IP address under a different Vagrant networking setup maybe?).
I wasn't sure if there are any good ideas out there as I tried googling and didnt have much luck.
Any ideas?

PS it would be great if i could do it without modifying the Android java source code. Maybe its possible to change the web service url in the Java code to point to the VM box's IP address. I haven't tried that yet, but was looking for some ideas first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your linux box is on the same network with your VM (your host to be precise) you can still use /etc/system/hosts they way you used it before, just point it to linux's IP.

Alternatively you can point VM to proxy so all HTTP traffic would go through it and then its up to you what proxy to use (depends on your host OS) and how to configure it to redirect to your linux box

Comment: So the Android VM i see is a simulated 3G connection (cant connect via Wifi to my wifi network). If I 'adb shell' into the Android VM, I just see 10.0.2.15 as the eth0 IP (not sure if its actually using it since it does 3G simulation)... The Vagrant VM defaults at 192.168.56.101 for its 'private_network' address (I could change to 'public_network' so get same ip range address as my laptop. so if my personal laptop is 192.168.1.248, then i would get 192.168.1.249 for the Vagrant VM web service). Either way, doesnt work if Android VM hosts has either the public or private ip's of the vagrant VM.

Comment: 2nd question about your alternative... How would your proxy all http traffic to the Vagrant VM (ssh forwarding or easier program on Windows to proxy)?

Comment: As per 2nd question it really depends on what you have handy, any win or Linux proxy would do

Comment: I got the hosts solution working. I converted both VMs to use Bridged Networking (the Android VM through a Genymotion VM, as I couldnt figure out how to do Bridged via normal Android VM i created with AVD Manager/AndroidStudio)  and setup Bridged Networking via 'public_network' for my Vagrant VM ... Then I 'adb pushed' the hosts file but apparently the /etc/system/hosts , which most tutorials/people seem to recommend, didnt work but on my VM /system/etc/hosts was the correct file instead.